# Obtener datos de una relacion muchos a muchos con EF y web-api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Una pregunta sencilla pero que no doy.
Tengo una relación muchos a muchos entre dos entidades Ciudadano y Topics (que se genera a partir de la tablas Ciudadano, Topics y CiudadanosTopics)

Y tengo un servicio Web-Api del que quiero obtener los Topics a los que esta suscrito un ciudadano. Para ello uso un método (que no funciona)

```
public IQueryable<Topic> GetTopics(string Ciudadano)
{
      db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      Ciudadano c = db.Ciudadanos.Include("RTopics").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Ciudadano);
      return c.RTopics.AsQueryable();

//      return db.Topics.Where(p => p.eliminado == false).OrderBy(o => o.nombreTopic); //ESTO SI FUNCIONA
}
```

Esto devuelve un error 500, aunque en RTopics este la lista de Topics a la que esta suscrita el ciudadano en cuestión.

Que falla?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Has depurado tu código para ver que está pasando? Es el `Id` de Ciudadano un string?

Comment: Si, la consulta es correcta, en c.RTopics hay un dato,que es lo que debería haber. Creo que el problema está en la forma de devolver los datos

Comment: En ese caso, el error no está en el código que nos muestras no?

Comment: En la depuración del código, el error lo pone error en la solicitud,1 solicitud 1 error, y en la descripción sale error 500, pero poco mas

Comment: Otra información importante es que edites tu pregunta y añadas el texto completo de la excepción. `Error 500` es un error genérico

Comment: No hay ninguna excepción, ese es el problema, si no sabría por donde esta el fallo. Cuando hago la petición, entra en el método y se ejecuta, no hay excepción, no hay interrupción de la ejecución, solo este error: Código de respuesta: 500
Id. de operación: ZbhEtGiCmwM=
Instancia de rol: ServidorWeb
Nombre de operación: GET Topics
Nombre de solicitud: GET Topics
Solicitud correcta: False
Tiempo de respuesta: 89ms
URL de solicitud: http://172.16.10.199/ws/api/Topics?Ciudadano=d4dbb81d-8e3f-4053-90fa-20ed7ab3ebca
Versión del SDK: web:2.2.0-738

Comment: Si modifico la función asi: public IQueryable<Topic> GetTopics(string Ciudadano)
      {
      db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      Ciudadano c = db.Ciudadanos.Include("RTopics").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Ciudadano);
      List<Topic> lista = c.RTopics.ToList();
      for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
        lista[i].RCiudadanos = null;
        lista[i].RNoticias = null;
        }
      return lista.AsQueryable();
      } Asi funciona, quitando las relaciones de los registros, pero no me parece una buena solucion

Answer (score 0):

Ademas de inhabilitar el `lazy load` deberias hacerlo tambien del `proxy`

[Entity Framework Working with Proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592886(v=vs.113).aspx)

utilizando la linea

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

quizas algo como ser

```
public List<Topic> GetTopics(string Ciudadano) 
{ 
    List<Topic> result = null;
    try
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 

        Ciudadano c = db.Ciudadanos
                            .Include("RTopics")
                            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Ciudadano); 

        result = c.RTopics.ToList();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string e = ex.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

igualmente veras que es aconsejable devolver un `List<>` y no un `IQueryable`, al ser una lista ya tendra resuelto la ejecucion del sql, quizas con este no afecte el proxy ni el lazy load

El inhabilitar el proxy y lazy load suelo colocalor en el contexto de EF

Comment: He probado tu codigo y obtengo el mismo error. Al ejecutar paso a paso, topics crea un objeto de ti ciudadado (y ciudadadno crea otros con los que esta relacionado) y noticia (que también esta relacionado)

Comment: Cuando creas la relacion muchos a muchos recuerda que la tabla intermedia no se define como clase en EF. Esto lo explico en el articulo  http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/07/entity-frameworkcode-first-asociacion_28.html

Comment: no afecta que ciudadano se relaciones con otras entidades ya que el return que realizas es de Topics. Recomendaria que definas el codigo dentro de un try...catch para ver si asi atrapas el error y se puede analizar el mensaje

Comment: He probado a poner el try..catch:   public List<Topic> GetTopics(string Ciudadano)
      {
      db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
      Ciudadano c = null;
      try
        {
        c = db.Ciudadanos.Include("RTopics").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Ciudadano);
        }
      catch (Exception ex)
        {
        string e = ex.ToString();
        }
      return c.RTopics.ToList();
      } y nada, pasa por el try y no entra en el catch pero sigue el mismo error 500.

Comment: pero el catch tiene que abarcar el return, o sea todo el codigo, edite la respuesta para poner el codigo de ejemplo, es en el ToList() donde se ejecuta realmente el linq

Comment: He hecho esto:  public List<Topic> GetTopics(string Ciudadano)
      {
      db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
      Ciudadano c = null;
      try
        {
        c = db.Ciudadanos.Include("RTopics").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Ciudadano);
        return c.RTopics.ToList();
        }
      catch (Exception ex)
        {
        string e = ex.ToString();
        return null;
        }
      }Nada de nada, pasa por el try, sale, y no salta ninguna excepción pero sigue el error 500

Comment: intentaste poner el try catch en el codigo de quien consume GetTopics() ? valida ademas que en la opcion de Exceptions del Visual Studio tengas habilitado que se detenga el codigo ante un error, esto es en el menu Debug->Windows->Exception Settings

Comment: En el servidor tengo esto: Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Request","time":"2017-11-15T11:49:52.6153093Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"web:2.2.0-738","ai.operation.id":"y1mi0C/N46c=","ai.location.ip":"192.168.10.19","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"ServidorHosting","ai.operation.name":"GET Topics"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"y1mi0C/N46c=","name":"GET Topics","duration":"00:00:03.6360000","success":false,"responseCode":"500","url":"http://192.168.10.199/ws/api/Topics?Ciudadano=d4dbb81d-8e3f-4053-90fa-20ed7aa"}}}

Comment: En el cliente ANDROID: Y en el cliente:
E/Volley: [194] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://192.168.10.199/ws/api/Topics?Ciudadano=d4dbb81d-8e3f-4053-90fa-20ed7ab3ebca
Y en el explorador ERROR 500 a secas. Ni excepción ni nada